# Plugins in Sublime stop working occasionally

Tags: sublimetext3

I really love using Sublime Text 3 and I have been using this editor for a while now. I really love some of the features of this editor, I have the following packages installed:

- color heighter
- JS-linting

I am particularly highly dependent on JS-linting, as it's really important to catch bugs right in the editor rather then later in the browser.

Below are the screenshots of how their plugins actually help me while developing:

Color highlighter

[image: highlighter]

Jslint

[image: JSlint]

Now this is a weird problem , but somehow their plugins work sometimes and sometimes they don't, there is no particular pattern, they just don't work sometimes, i.e. sometimes I will have obvious bugs in my editor and the JSlinter will not even highlight them. Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

### Edit

I see the following errors in my console:

```
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 1537, in on_query_completions
    lang = guess_lang(view)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 459, in guess_lang
    mgr = None if settings_manager._settings_id is None else codeintel_manager()
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 769, in codeintel_manager
    condeintel_log_file = open(condeintel_log_filename, 'w', 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\gautamz07/.codeintel\\codeintel.log'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 272, in on_modified
    callback.on_modified(v)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 1441, in on_modified
    lang = guess_lang(view, path, sublime_scope)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 459, in guess_lang
    mgr = None if settings_manager._settings_id is None else codeintel_manager()
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 769, in codeintel_manager
    condeintel_log_file = open(condeintel_log_filename, 'w', 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\gautamz07/.codeintel\\codeintel.log'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 240, in on_pre_save
    callback.on_pre_save(v)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 1419, in on_pre_save
    lang = guess_lang(view)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 459, in guess_lang
    mgr = None if settings_manager._settings_id is None else codeintel_manager()
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 769, in codeintel_manager
    condeintel_log_file = open(condeintel_log_filename, 'w', 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\gautamz07/.codeintel\\codeintel.log'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 272, in on_modified
    callback.on_modified(v)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 1441, in on_modified
    lang = guess_lang(view, path, sublime_scope)
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 459, in guess_lang
    mgr = None if settings_manager._settings_id is None else codeintel_manager()
  File "C:\Users\gautamz07\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeCodeIntel\SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 769, in codeintel_manager
    condeintel_log_file = open(condeintel_log_filename, 'w', 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\gautamz07/.codeintel\\codeintel.log'
(snipped)
```

[Full log is here](http://pastebin.com/4eiWRqZL)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a permission issue:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\gautamz07/.codeintel\\codeintel.log'
```

To fix that, you can open `C:\Users\gautamz07/.codeintel` directory for writing. For example, for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 the instructions can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to me a couple of times. The easiest way to fix this is to Uninstall and Reinstall the Sublime Package manager.